# Calculate and plot correlation & confidence intervals of one variable against multiple variables

Tags: r, plot, correlation

I have the following data (this is a head, the actual data is >100 rows) consisting of all ordinal variables.  In the real data, "Beds" ranges from 1 to 8, and all the "Test" variables range from 1 to 4.  I want to calculate and plot the correlation of each "Testx" variable against "Beds," but I don't want a full matrix as I do not want to correlate "Testx" variables against each other.

Here is a csv of the data ... I save it as "test.csv"

```
Beds,Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4,Test5,Test6,Test7,Test8
4,4,1,4,4,4,4,3,4
1,3,1,1,1,1,4,2,1
2,4,1,1,2,4,1,1,1
1,4,1,1,4,1,1,1,1
1,2,1,1,1,4,2,2,2
1,4,1,1,1,2,1,1,1
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
1,4,1,1,4,3,2,2,1
```

EDIT:

I've got a kluge that works but is not elegant:

```
test <- read.csv("test.csv")

#Initialize results table as blank dataframe
cTable <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=5, nrow=0))
colnames(cTable) <- c("Test", "Cor", "cL", "cH", "p")

#Begin correlation calculation for Test 1
df <- cor.test(test$Beds, test$Test1)

#Pull the 95% confidence interval and break it into upper and lower limits
interv <- as.character(df$conf.int)
cL <- as.numeric(strsplit(interv, " ")[[1]]) #lower 95% confidence limit
cH <- as.numeric(strsplit(interv, " ")[[2]]) #upper 95% confidence limit

t <- data.frame(Test="Test1", Cor=df$estimate, cL=cL, cH=cH, p=df$p.value)
rownames(t)<-NULL

cTable <- rbind(cTable, t)

rm(df,t) #Repeat code doesn't work unless temporary dataframes are cleared out

#Repeat for Test5
df <- cor.test(test$Beds, test$Test5)

interv <- as.character(df$conf.int)
cL <- as.numeric(strsplit(interv, " ")[[1]])
cH <- as.numeric(strsplit(interv, " ")[[2]])

t <- data.frame(Test="Test5", Cor=df$estimate, cL=cL, cH=cH, p=df$p.value)
rownames(t)<-NULL

cTable <- rbind(cTable, t)

rm(df,t)
```

This works, though it's probably not the best way to do what I want since I now have to repeat it for Test2 through Test8.  But it works.  I ran it for Test1 and Test5 because, as it happens, the confidence intervals for Test2 are undefined.  This isn't a problem in the live data.  Here's the output:

```
   Test       Cor          cL        cH          p
1 Test1 0.3947710 -0.31253956 0.8204642 0.25890218
2 Test5 0.5921565 -0.05974491 0.8899691 0.07128552
```

The ultimate output should have a row for each Testx.

The other desired output is a plot with each Textx as an ordinal on the X axis, and the correlation coefficient on the Y axis, with the coefficient plus confidence intervals shown.  That part turned out to be easy:

```
ggplot(cTable, aes(x=cTable$Test, y=cTable$Cor))+
  geom_point(size=4)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=cTable$cH, ymin=cTable$cL))
```

Which produces:

[image: Plot of correlations with confidence intervals]

So in summary, I have what I need, but it isn't pretty to get there.  It seems to me there ought to be a way to replace the repeat code above with some command that takes the one column "Beds" and correlates it against all the other columns in turn, producing the same output I've got here.

Comment: What did you already try and why did it fail? Please add some sample code.

Comment: I don't know what to try ... I thought I explained that.  I can get the correlations using cor.test, but can't find any way to grab and tabulate or operate on the output.  I'm sorry, I don't know where to start.

Comment: I also can find nothing that says how to calculate correlations across a table, correlating one variable against multiple other variables.

Comment: **Self Promotion**:You can try `get_var_corr` from a package I wrote known as [`manymodelr`](https://github.com/Nelson-Gon/manymodelr/tree/develop). It may be useful in this case. It currently only returns correlations.

Comment: With or without confidence intervals?  I really need to get both.

Comment: You might be able to tweak it and get them. I cannot do that right now but will possibly try some time.

Comment: "Beds" contains numbers from 1 to 8.  And you're right on cor.test, I mixed it up with some other functions I like.  Yes, it's base.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it.  The answer is in corr.test, part of the "psych" package. It just requires subsetting the output to select only the correlations I want and discarding the rest.

```
library("ggplot2")
library("data.table") #used for the %like% string operator
library ("psych")  #used for the corr.test function

test <- read.csv("test.csv")

cTab <- print(corr.test(test, use = "pairwise", method = "pearson", adjust = "none"), short=FALSE)
cTab <- cTab[rownames(cTab) %like% "Beds",] #Subsets the variable whose correlations I actually want
cTab$names <- rownames(cTab) #so I can use the rownames as the X variable

ggplot(cTab, aes(x=cTab$names, y=cTab$raw.r))+
  geom_point(size=4)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=cTab$raw.upper, ymin=cTab$raw.lower), width=0.3, size=0.75)+
  labs(x="Test", y="Correlation Coefficient")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust=0.5, face = "italic"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1.0))
```

Here's what the output looks like (remember Test2 has bad data, I didn't bother fixing it)
[image: Correlation coefficients with confidence intervals]